# FosUser: password email is not sending with template

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I  am trying to send password reset email. These are my configurations

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: CoreBundle\Entity\User
    service:
            user_manager: pugx_user_manager
    registration:
            confirmation:
                enabled: true
                template: AppBundle:Email:registration.email.twig
                from_email:
                    address:        noreply@hello.com
                    sender_name:    Hello
    resetting:
            token_ttl: 43200
            email:
                template: AppBundle:Email:password_reset.email.twig
                from_email:
                    address:        noreply@hello.com
                    sender_name:    Hello
```

I tried to send emails by calling mailer service in controller:

```
  $this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendResettingEmailMessage($testUser);
```

It doesn't work. However if I remove template, everything works fine. Emails are sent, but for me it's important to customise template.

My email settings are all good, registration confirm template customisation worked fine. I don't understand why resetting doesn't work

Comment: I use the same configuration as you and I can customize resetting template. Some questions: Do your bundle extends FOSUserBundle? Do you override bundle templates/controllers inside your bundle?

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers I extended my bundle from FosUser, but I didn't override controllers

Comment: Well, I override also controllers (even if I am not sure it is adressing your issue). Just want to tell you what I do for exactly same scenario: I extend FOSUser bundle, copy controllers and templates files in my bundle and customize what I want hope it helps

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers I didn't need to override anything to customise and send registration confirmation email, that's why I thought it could be done without all this dirty work :(

Comment: The goal from extending a bundle afaik, is to make customization inside your bundle by overriding fosuer templates/controllers (copying them and keeping them with same names ). I don't fully get your approach and witing for expert to enlight us here

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers I have noticed that if I remove {{ confirmationUrl }} from template, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure a different mailer service in the fos-user configuration, like:

```
   fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template: email/registrationconfirmation.html.twig
```